# Expo Video Player , Add customized Ad

Tags: react-native, expo, video-player

I am Trying To add a customized Ad to my Expo App, it should be playing before the video starts , is there a way to add another video(customized Ad )  before the video start playing . Is there any way to add the Ad to the video .